# how to find a position of an Object from World Space and convert to Canvas UI with render mode : Screen Space - Camera in Unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uiviewanimation, game-development

I am working in a Game which is pretty similar to Mario. So when player touches the coin object in World Space, I need to animate by moving that coin object to Coin meter, when the render mode of Canvas is **Screen Space - Overlay**, I can get the sprite object position easily with below code

**CoinSprite Code**

```
GameObject coinCanvasObject = Instantiate(prefab, canvas.transform);//Instantiate coin inside Canvas view
coinCanvasObject.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(coinSpriteObject.transform.position);//getting coin position from World Space and convert to Screen Space and set to coinCanvasobject position 
AnimateCoin animate = coinCanvasObject.GetComponent<AnimateCoin>();
animate.animateCoin(coinSpriteObject.transform.position);
coinSpriteObject.SetActive(false);
```

**AnimateCoin**

```
public class AnimateCoin : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 0f;
    private bool isSpawn = false;
    private Vector3 screenPos;

    public void animateCoin(Vector3 screenPosTemp, Camera cam, Canvas canvas)
    {
        screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(screenPosTemp);
        isSpawn = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isSpawn)
        {
            speed += 0.025f;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(screenPos, targetObject.transform.position, speed);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetObject.transform.position) <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(deActivateCoin());
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator deActivateCoin()
    {
        isSpawn = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }    
}
```

Since I need to bring particle effect into Canvas view, I am changing the Canvas render mode to **Screen Space -  Camera**.
When I change the Canvas to this render mode I could not get the exact sprite object position to trail the coin effect.

Comment: But if the coin is a child of the Canvas anyway can't you simply spawn your trail effect at the same local position also as child of the canvas?

Comment: Initially the coin will be in world space and when player catch the coin, I Instantiate another coin object inside the Canvas and set the world space coin object position to this newly Instantiated object and then do the animation.

Comment: Ah I see, just for my understand you want to have something like: Have a 3D coin -> User clicks it -> is replaced with a 2D coin Sprite in the canvas -> animate/move into a certain position in the canvas with trail?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you solved it? I want particle effects on GUI so I need Screen Space-Camera but when you have this on, you cant get the world position of the GUI. And the player is moving continuously in my case so the world position of rectransform is changing...

Comment: No I could not solve this issue. I need to show confetti effect in GUI and I solved it by getting animation sprite from my designer. But all particles effects cannot be done through animation that is why I am afraid off.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
public Camera           cam;    // Camera containing the canvas
public Transform        target; // object in the 3D World
public RectTransform    icon;   // icon to place in the canvas
public Canvas           canvas; // canvas with "Render mode: Screen Space - Camera"

void Update()
{
    Vector3 screenPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
    float h = Screen.height;
    float w = Screen.width;
    float x = screenPos.x - (w / 2);
    float y = screenPos.y - (h / 2);
    float s = canvas.scaleFactor;
    icon.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y) / s;
}
```

PD: It worked perfectly for me in a 2D video game, I didn't test it in a 3D game, but I think it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my previous solution because it might not work correctly on some devices with non-standard resolutions.

This code should always work.

```
uiObject.anchoredPosition = GetUIScreenPosition(myPin.position, cam3d, uiObject.anchorMin);

public static Vector2 GetUIScreenPosition(Vector3 obj3dPosition, Camera cam3d, Vector2 anchor)
    {
       Vector2 rootScreen = _rootCanvasRect.sizeDelta;
       Vector3 screenPos = cam3d.WorldToViewportPoint(obj3dPosition);
       return (rootScreen * screenPos) - (rootScreen * anchor);
    }
```

We take the sizeDelta of our UI Canvas, because it may differ from the screen resolution of the device.

Then we cast the WorldToViewportPoint from our 3d camera to get the relative position on the screen in the format from 0 to 1 by X and Y.

With anchors in the lower left corner ((0,0)(0,0)) this is our final anchoredPosition. However with anchors for example in the center ((0.5,0.5)(0.5,0.5)) we need to adjust the positions by subtracting half the canvas size.

In this example, we will get an unpredictable result when using different min and max anchors in the final object. For example ((0,25,0.25)(0.75,0.75)). But I sincerely doubt that you really need such anchors on an object with a dynamic position depending on the 3d object.